# How do I search for a string in a MySQL table using node-orm2?

Tags: mysql, express, orm, node-orm2

I want to search through a table for a particular string. I can find the row when the tag matches the contents exactly. But I want to find all occurrences of `"red"` even when the tags column has multiple colors in a string like `"blue, green, purple, red"`. Is it possible to use SQL to query? I found a vague reference involving chaining but it wasn't clear how to make it work in this case.

Here's what I have for the exact match...

```
app.post("/admin/search", function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    req.models.images.find({tags:data.tags}, function(err, results) {
         res.send(results); //Returns on perfect match
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
    app.post("/admin/search", function(req, res) {
        var data = req.body;
        req.models.images.find().where("tags LIKE ?",["%"+data.tags+"%"]).run(function(err,results){
            res.send(results);
        });
    });
```